# Laravel: how to create scopes massively?

Tags: php, laravel

To create a scope in Laravel, we define manually a public method that matches the name that we want to use when building queries:

```
/**
 * Scope of Microsoft organization.
 * 
 * @param Builder $query
 * @return Builder
 */
public function scopeMicrosoft($query) 
{
    return $query->where('slug', 'microsoft');
}
```

Usage:

```
Organization::microsoft()->first();
```

Now imagine that we have >50 organizations and want to automatically have a scope for every model based on `slug` attribute. There's a way to create scopes massively?

Comment: The term "massively" in this context is rather confusing and you might want to amend your question to make it clearer. Do you mean you want to be able to define it once and then call them dynamically eg `scopeApple()`, `scopeOracle()` etc?

Comment: @MatthewDaly exactly!

Comment: To be honest, Tpojka's answer covers this fairly well in that there's no reason why you can't just pass the name of the organisation in question as an argument, eg `organisation('Microsoft')`, and it. You can do this kind of thing with [PHP's __call magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call), but the problem is that Eloquent already uses it so doing so is going to be tricky without breaking the existing functionality. For what it's worth you're better off just passing the organisation name as an argument.

Comment: When you call any existing scope, that's already hitting `__call()` in `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`, so it's going to be fiddly to handle that and catch these method calls without causing problems. It can probably be done, but it's likely to be more trouble than its worth just for a little bit of syntactic sugar.

Comment: Also, since the scopes already use `__call()` to effectively rewrite the method name, then they're particularly tricky to do this with.

Answer (score 2):

From [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#query-scopes):

**Dynamic Scopes**

> Sometimes you may wish to define a scope that accepts parameters. To get started, just add your additional parameters to your scope. Scope parameters should be defined after the  $query parameter:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SomeModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * Scope a query to only include users of a given type.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
     * @param mixed $type
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeOrganization($query, $org)
    {
        return $query->where('slug', $org);
    }
}
```

Now, you may pass the parameters when calling the scope:

```
$users = App\SomeModel::organization('Microsoft')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [global scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#global-scopes) if you're going to use this scope in all models.

Or add this local scope into a trait and use it in multiple models.

Comment: This is not the point. The question is: "how to create scopes automatically based on an model attribute".

Comment: @AlexandreThebaldi well, the question was "There's a way to create scopes massively" and I answered that. What exactly do you mean by `based on a model attribute`?

Answer (score 0):

Use this package for dynamic global scope make,
https://github.com/limewell/laravel-make-extender

php artisan make:scope ActiveScope

php artisan make:scope UserScope

php artisan make:scope AgeScope etc...